# Dockerized C# Application dll can't be found

Tags: c#, docker, .net-assembly

My API call is throwing a 500 hundred error because it cannot locate the dll file. The dll file exists inside the published folder. I can see it in the container shell (Submissions.ITCollect.API.Models.dll). This dll file is located inside of the /lib folder. Also, including my dockerfile below. I'm unsure of how to correct this issue.

[image: Docker Cli]

[image]

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS base
ARG buildconfig=1.0.0
ARG api_version=1.0.0
ARG package_version=1.0.0
ARG solutionFile=Folio.Portfolio.Api.sln
ARG api_project=Portfolio.API
ARG api_dll=Portfolio.API.dll
ENV api_dll="${api_dll}"
ARG run_test
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /
COPY $solutionFile .
WORKDIR /src
COPY /src .

WORKDIR /
# set the path so that the dotnet tool can be found
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools" 
RUN if [ "${run_test}" = "test" ]; then \
    # install dotcover tool globally
    dotnet tool install JetBrains.dotCover.GlobalTool --global ; \
    # run the unit tests with code coverage
    dotnet dotcover test $solutionFile --dcReportType=HTML --dcAttributeFilters=System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute ; \
    else \
    # create mock coverage files so that we dont need to handle conditional copy
    mkdir dotCover.Output; \
    echo "mock report" >> /dotCover.Output/coverage.html ;\
    echo "mock report" >> dotCover.Output.html ;\
    fi

WORKDIR /src/$api_project
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build -p:Version=$api_version
RUN dotnet pack -o /app/publish -p:PackageVersion=$package_version
RUN if [ "${buildconfig}" = "Debug" ]; then \
    dotnet publish "${api_project}.csproj" -o /app/publish -c Debug; \
    else \
    dotnet publish "${api_project}.csproj" -o /app/publish -c Release; \
    fi

COPY /lib /app/publish/

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=base /app/publish .
COPY --from=base /dotCover.Output.html ./dotCover.Output.html
COPY --from=base /dotCover.Output ./dotCover.Output

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec dotnet ${api_dll}"]
```

Comment: maybe its looking in a different path

Comment: There is no trace about how you load DLLs from the lib folder, try to copy the content of the lib folder up to one level (same level as the `${api_dll}`.